# How to avoid multiplication when click on combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Hello when you click on a field of the combobox and automatic all values are doubled. Once they clicked once again they are tripled again.
How can I fix that ?

My code:

```
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.selectOnlyWorkerName(), connection);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["worker_name"]);
    }
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: you have to clear the combobox

Answer (score 3):

You are adding same data again and again when you click, so clear the combobox when you click, add following line:

comboBox1.Items.Clear();

Try the following code:

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(service.selectOnlyWorkerName(), connection);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["worker_name"]);
    }
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Not work, when I click on some values I cant delete becouse combobox is empty:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What do you want to delete?

Comment: If you add the code block inside your click event it will add items to your combobox, now what do you want to delete?

Comment: I try with the same example here but when I want to see values in the combo, the combo is empty becouse when connection is oppened this code clear the combo. I want wen I click on some values in the combo to avoid multiplication

Comment: Do you want to load the items when you click on some values in combobox?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to clear the comboboxx

Simple  code:

```
 Comboboxname.Items.Clear();
```